# Google Maps API (bug?) - Mousedown stuck when map hand drag starts on 'to-be-editable' polygon point

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygons

My apologies for the subject name, but I believe I've found a relatively easy bug to replicate, in which clicking and dragging on the map in a particular point on a polygon sticks the map into a "mouse-down drag" state that is difficult to get out of.

It's much easier to show this problem.  How to recreate:

http://jsfiddle.net/un0a0ua5/

1. Ensure that polygon is not editable (no point markers on vertices)
2. Move your cursor to any vertice where the vertice would be shown upon clicking (top right is easiest to reproduce), ensure that it has the 1-finger pointer cursor
3. Click and drag the mouse like you're scrolling to a different area on the map, let go of the mouse button
4. You're now stuck like your mouse is still down, moving the map centered on the vertice, the only way to break from it is scrolling the mouse wheel.

I'm not sure if this is a Google Maps bug, or if I should be able to manually trigger a 'mouseup' event on the map to release the hold.

I was able to reproduce this on Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu, and Chrome on Windows.  I can provide more detail if needed.

Any thoughts?

Reproducible from:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
    zoom: 14,
});

var new_poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: [{lat: 33.808678, lng: -117.916921}, {lat: 33.818678, lng:-117.914921}, {lat: 33.801678, lng:-117.928921}],
  strokeColor: '#000000',
  fillColor: '#000000'});

google.maps.event.addListener(new_poly, 'mousedown', function() {
    console.log('POLYGON->MOUSE_DOWN');
    new_poly.setOptions({editable:true});
});

new_poly.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the event to 'mouseup' solves the problem, but it still seems like a Google Maps API v3 bug.